# how to do vector appending intelligently in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix, append

My aim is to create some matrix having 'n' row vectors. I have coded this, but unable to represent it as a matrix of row vectors, instead I am stuck with a single vector which contains the concatenated 'n' sub vectors. My matlab code goes as follows :

```
At=20;
k=0.1;
n=2;
dt=0.005;
A=At;

AA=zeros(length(1,1:dt:30));

for j=1:n
for i=1:dt:(30-dt)

r =rand;

         if (r<(k*At*dt))
             At=At-1;
             A=cat(2,A,At);
         else
             A=cat(2,A,At);  
         end

end
At=20;
end
```

How to do this cleverly?

Comment: How to delete this question? I understand this is done previously by others.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but you can try something like this:

```
for j=1:n
   for i=1:dt:(30-dt)

      r =rand;

      if (r<(k*At*dt))
          At=At-1;
      end
      A(j,i) = At;
   end
   At=20;
end
```

where `A` should be initialised properly (e.g. `A = zeros(n,T)`).

BTW: `i` and `j` are very poor choices of variables in Matlab since they normally represent the imaginary unit (`sqrt(-1)`)